# Condition for the line $x+y=3$ is a tangent to the curve $y=\frac{ax}{1+x}$

Tags: proof-verification, tangent-line

The question is as follows:

> For what values of '$a$'($\in\mathbb R$) is the line $x+y=3$ a tangent to the curve $y=\dfrac{ax}{1+x}$?

The answer: *No such '$a$' exists.*

How do I solve this question?

---

What I've tried:

If the line $x+y=3$ is a tangent to the curve $y=\dfrac{ax}{1+x}$ at some point $(x_1,y_1)$ on the curve, then we know that the slope of the tangent $(-1)$ is equal to $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at the point $(x_1,y_1)$.

$$\implies\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{ax}{1+x}\right)\Bigg|_{x=x_1}=-1$$
$$\implies\dfrac{a}{(1+x_1)^2}=-1$$
$$\implies (1+x_1)^2=-a$$

Which is not possible for $a\in\mathbb R^+$.

---

My working is only halfway to the solution, what am I doing wrong?

Suggestions for other ways of solving this question will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us find the abscissa of intersection

$$\dfrac{ax}{1+x}=3-x$$

$$\implies x^2+x(a-2)-3=0$$

For tangency both roots must be same, $\implies$ the discriminant must be $0$

But the discriminant $=(a-2)^2+12\ge12>0$ for real $a$